# azureで仮想マシンにデプロイ

Tags: azure

azureでDevOpsを使い、Reposのリポジトリから、パイプラインを使いビルドとデプロイをしたいと考えています。

仮想マシンはWindows Server 2019です。

１．アップするのは、phpファイルだけなので、パイプライン作成時にphpを選択して、
アーティファクトを公開するための記述をしました。

azure-pipelines.yml

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
  
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'    

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1    
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

２．enviromentsを設定し、仮想マシンのpowershellでアクセストークン？のｺｰﾄﾞを実行しました。

Reposのリポジトリもローカルからpushして設定しました。

３．リリースパイプラインを作成しました。
これは、azureポータルの仮想マシンの継続的デリバリーから設定しました。

これで
ローカルからazure Reposにpushして、ビルドパイプラインは成功して、Repos上のファイルも更新されました。
リリースパイプラインは、トリガーを設定していないので、手動で動かして成功しました。
deployments/deploy.ps1のデプロイスクリプトが必要だと言われましたが、
よくわからなかったので、inlineを選択したら、通りました。

その後、仮想マシンの、`C:\AzurePiplinesAgent_Extension\_work\r1\a\_build\drop`に、ファイルがアップされましたが、
ファイルを更新して、もう1度リリースパイプラインを動かしても、ファイルは更新されませんでした。

再度実行する前に、このデプロイ先？のフォルダを変更したかったので、
`$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` の部分に直接パスを入れて実行しましたができませんでした。

その後、戻して、もう1度実行しましたが、dorp下にあるファイルも更新されませんでした。
特にエラーログも出ていないので、なぜファイルが更新されないのかわかりません。

知りたいのは、`C:\AzurePiplinesAgent_Extension\_work\r1\a\_build\drop`　このフォルダがデプロイ先なのか、そうであれば、のフォルダの変更の仕方がしりたいです。

また、仮想マシンへのCICDの方法として、上記の方法で、方針としてはあっているのか、yamlファイルはこれでよいのかアドバイスいただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: いくつか間違いがあるので訂正します。
Reposは1より前に設定しました。
piplineは、starterを選択しました。
imageはwindows-latestとしています。

VMの継続デリバリーから、ほかのプロジェクトを接続して、以下のyamlファイルでパイプラインを動作させました。
Reposへのpush後にビルドからデプロイが自動で動作しましたが、

Comment: C:\AzurePiplinesAgent_Extension\_work\r1\a\_build-deploy　のフォルダが作成されただけで、ファイルはアップされてませんでした。
これは、 PathtoPublishが設定されていないためと考えました。
なので、以下のようにyamlファイルを作成し、動作させましたが、ファイルがアップされませんでした。

Comment: ```
trigger:
- master

stages:
- stage: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-latest
  jobs:
  - job: build
    steps:
    - script: echo Hello, world!
      displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

    - script: |
        echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
        echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
      displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
      condition: 

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

Comment: - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1    
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: build-deploy'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'


- stage: Release
  dependsOn:
  - Build
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployWeb
    displayName: deploy Web App
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    # creates an environment if it doesn't exist
    environment: '環境名'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo Hello world

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/ou8dzzmlun0g9w     こちらにも書きました。